# Qt assign lines from textfile to qlabels

Tags: c++, qt

What works so far: opening a textfile via `QFileDialog` and showing the contents of the textfile in a `Qlabel`(showfile).
I too have a `for-loop` that counts how many `\n` are in the textfile.
Now what I want is that line after line in the textfile is assigned to a new `Qlabel` meaning each `Qlabel` contains one line of the textfile and place it dynamically on runtime.

Maybe you can help since I´m a little stuck here.

Here´s my qwidget class where the labels should be placed:

```
class mywidget:public QWidget       //class for displaying everything
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QGridLayout *area;
    QLabel *showfile;               //shows input from textfile
    QLabel *processname,*status;    //captionlabel
    QFont *pfont,*sfont;            //fontoption for processname&status
    QLabel **processes;             //2D array to dynamically create QLabels for each entry in file


public:
    mywidget(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0):QWidget(parent,flags)
    {
        this->area = new QGridLayout(this);
        this->showfile = new QLabel(tr("Test"),this);
        this->pfont = new QFont();
        this->pfont->setPixelSize(20);
        this->sfont = new QFont();
        this->sfont->setPixelSize(20);
        this->processname = new QLabel(tr("Process_Name:"),this);
        this->processname->setFont(*pfont);
        this->status = new QLabel(tr("Status:"),this);
        this->status->setFont(*sfont);
        this->area->addWidget(this->processname,0,0,Qt::AlignHCenter);
        this->area->addWidget(this->status,0,1,Qt::AlignHCenter);
        this->area->addWidget(this->showfile,1,0,Qt::AlignHCenter);
        this->area->setSpacing(10);
    }
    ~mywidget()
    {
        delete this->area;
        delete this->showfile;
        delete this->pfont;
        delete this->sfont;
        delete this->processname;
        delete this->status;
    }
    friend class mywindow;
};
```

And here is my open-method from QMainwindow class:

```
void mywindow::oeffnen()
{
    this->openfilename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName              //open textfile dialog
        (this,
         tr("Datei öffnen"),
         QDir::homePath(),
         "Textdateien (*.txt *.docx *.doc);;" "Alle Dateien (*.*)"
         );

    if(!this->openfilename.isEmpty())
    {
        this->file = new QFile(this->openfilename);
        this->file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        this->stream = new QTextStream(this->file);
        this->fileread = this->stream->readAll();



        for(int z = 0;z<this->fileread.length();++z)                //check entries in string by counting \n
        { 
            this->eintraege = this->fileread.count(QRegExp("\n"));
        }
        //this->s_eintraege = QString::number(this->eintraege);       //converting to string for displaying





        this->central->showfile->setText(this->fileread);           //assign filecontent to label



        if(!this->file->isReadable())
        {
            QMessageBox::information(this,
                                     tr("Fehler"),
                                     tr("Konnte Datei %1 nicht laden!").arg(this->openfilename)
                                     );
        }
        else
        {
            QMessageBox::information(this,
                                     tr("OK"),
                                     tr("Konnte Datei %1 laden!").arg(this->openfilename)
                                     );
        }
        this->file->close();    
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use vertical layout , add the vertical layout into gridlayout. At runtime keep adding the new labels into vertical layout. You don't need to delete labels explicitly in destructor. Qt parent child relationship will take care of that.

Comment: Why do you want to read each line to a new `QLabel`?

Comment: For displaying purposes ;-) and I need every line of the file in a seperate QString to use it as a source path to launch new processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new `QLabel` into a layout for each new line you read from a file. You can store the labels in a [container](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html) like [`QVector`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html) so you can access their text later on. Here is an example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFile>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>

class DisplayWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    DisplayWidget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        labelLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
        setLayout(labelLayout);
        resize(200, 200);
    }
    void addLabel(const QString &text)
    {
        QLabel *label = new QLabel(text);
        label_vector.append(label);
        labelLayout->addWidget(label);
    }
    void readFile(const QString &filename)
    {
        QFile file(filename);
        if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
            return;
        QTextStream ts(&file);
        while(!ts.atEnd())
        {
            QString line = ts.readLine();
            if(!line.isEmpty())
                addLabel(line);
        }
    }
    QString getLabelText(int index)
    {
        if(label_vector.size() > index)
            return label_vector[index]->text();
        return QString();
    }

private:
    QVBoxLayout *labelLayout;
    QVector<QLabel*> label_vector;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    DisplayWidget w;
    w.readFile("somefile.txt");
    w.show();
    qDebug() << w.getLabelText(3);

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Great, that was what I needed :-)